# Font where small case letters, are just smaller big case letters

Tags: frameworks, fonts

I am looking for a font where small case letters will be just smaller big case letters.

Why i need this is because on one of our embedded devices we have lots of sub-scripted text, and .NET compact framework doesn't support sub-scripting text in buttons. So if i can find a font that does that i don't need to write custom controls for everything.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "trajan pro" font.